# how it's possible to assign a Float64 to an NSInteger variable?

Tags: objective-c

How this function can work ?

```
- (NSInteger)selectFpsForFormat:(AVCaptureDeviceFormat *)format {
  Float64 maxSupportedFramerate = 0;
  for (AVFrameRateRange *fpsRange in format.videoSupportedFrameRateRanges) {
    maxSupportedFramerate = fmax(maxSupportedFramerate, fpsRange.maxFrameRate);
  }
  return fmin(maxSupportedFramerate, kFramerateLimit);
}
```

because `return fmin(maxSupportedFramerate, kFramerateLimit);` it's an float64 not an NSInteger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because Objective-C is C, and the [C specification](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) states:

> 6.3 Conversions
>
> 6.3.1 Arithmetic operands
>
> 6.3.1.4 Real floating and integer
>
> 1 When a finite value of real floating type is converted to an integer type other than _Bool, the fractional part is discarded (i.e., the value is truncated toward zero). If the value of the integral part cannot be represented by the integer type, the behavior is undefined.

See also the definition of the `return` statement for why arithmetic conversion applies in this case:

> 6.8.6.4 The return statement
>
> 3 If a return statement with an expression is executed, the value of the expression is returned to the caller as the value of the function call expression. If the expression has a type different from the return type of the function in which it appears, the value is converted as if by assignment to an object having the return type of the function.

And then go read up on 6.5.16.1.3 Simple assignment.... you can keep going down the rabbit hole of the spec, as deep as you like. :D

But the key point is, in C, floating point values can be implicitly converted to integers, and there is specified way that thy are converted.

Answer (score 0):

To be more clear, you can add an explicit cast:

```
return (NSInteger)fmin(maxSupportedFramerate, kFramerateLimit);
```

But that is not changing the behaviour as it will be done automatically as Rob explained.